# How much does time control affect ELO strength?

Tags: elo, time-control

Suppose we cloned Magnus Carlsen and arranged a match between the clone and the real Magnus. I will give the real Magnus x minutes on his clock, and the clone will have y minutes. Is there any research on what is the expected result of the match for a given pair x, y? Thanks

Comment: This is very variable. It will be very different for different players and again for different time controls. You are inviting speculation, particularly with your use of a counterfactual example, rather than a sensible answer.

Comment: The example seems very odd. Are you asking if one player has the same strength playing different time controls ? i.e if he is 2700 in classic, if he will always be 2700 also in blitz and bullet ?

Comment: @Isac no. I am asking the winning probability of "the same player" playing against him/herself with different time controls.